# how to make downloads through a proxy exceeding proxi's download file size limit?

Tags: browser, proxy, download, firewall

I am using an internet connection through a proxy. It does not allow me to download files larger that 50MB. I want to make downloads exceeding that limit. What are the techniques and methods I can use ?

If the download link is "https", proxy lets to download it. I think it happens because the proxy cannot understand the size the download when it is "https". But most of the downloads are in "http"